# Using inferential statistics with groups that are unequal in size

Tags: sample, unbalanced-classes, group-differences

I do clinical research and I am often asked to compare groups of vastly different group sizes. I try and get my clinicians to collapse categories when possible. I would like to definitively say that you cannot compare three groups with ns of 1, 10, and 98. Another example would be ns of 3, 60, 40.

Comment: There is no general requirement of similar group sizes when comparing independent groups by descriptive or inductive methods. If it makes sense from a medical point of view, I can easily use a Kruskal-Wallis test to compare the groups in your examples as long the variances are not too different between groups.

Comment: While, admittedly, groups of size 1 do not help (degrees of freedoms do not increase)

Comment: @Michael's right, what you'd like to say simply isn't true. Why do you think it is? If you plan an experiment, balanced group sizes are usually a good idea - to maximize power & sometimes to make analysis more robust to violation of assumptions - but that's all.